# How do I sync apps from two computers

Tags: 11.10, sync

I have a computer with Ubuntu 11.10 at School and now my Laptop I typically use only at home that I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on to it. How can I get it so that when I install an app on one computer next time I log in and connect to the net it will sync with what apps the other computer has? I already figured and and set up Ubuntu One so that is not an issue, i.e. file sharing.

Answer (score 2):

The current implementation of ubuntu one does not yet support automatic app syncing. However, if you open the Software Center and navigate to "File>Sync Between Computers" you can see each machine hooked up and manually install the missing apps yourself.

The feature will come soon!

Answer (score 0):

From `man dpkg`:

```
  To make a local copy of the package selection states:
        dpkg --get-selections >myselections

   You might transfer this file to another computer, and install it there with:
        dpkg --clear-selections
        dpkg --set-selections <myselections

   Note that this will not actually install or remove anything, but just set the  selection  state  on
   the  requested  packages. You will need some other application to actually download and install the
   requested packages. For example, run apt-get dselect-upgrade.
```